# Is there a way to estimate table or field size in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am designing a schema that will be used for analytics. In order to properly decide how far do I go with de-normalization of data, I need to estimate the size of columns in the target schema.
I am looking for a way to predict the size of a column in a BQ table based on the info I have (data type, cardinality, avg (or percentile) string length, # of records etc.).

Are there any heuristics or other methods to roughly estimate column size?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a BigQuery field is based on the type:

- BOOLEAN: 1 byte
- INTEGER: 8 bytes
- FLOAT: 8 bytes
- TIMESTAMP: 8 bytes
- STRING: Length of UTF8 encoding + 2 bytes

With some special cases:

- NULL values (for any type): 0 bytes
- REPEATED field: Sum of size of values in the repeated field.

Comment: The compression ratio is not used for billing purposes -- the full, uncompressed size is used.

Comment: what would be the size of TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: The size of a timestamp is also 8 bytes (answer edited above)