# I have loaded a 1.5GB csv file and successfully loading my table size is 250MB why this is so?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

In google Bigquery ....I have loaded a  1.5GB csv file from googlstorage after successfully loading,.... my table size is 250MB why this is so?

Answer (score 6):

Likely because the binary encoding of numbers is more efficient than encoding them as strings. For example, the string `"1234567890"` takes 10 bytes (at least, or 20 bytes if it is UTF-16 encoded), but it can be represented by a 4 byte integer which only takes, ehm, 4 bytes.

Furthermore, the table in bigquery can also leave out the separators, because it knows how many bytes each field is wide. Thats another byte saved for every `,`.

Comment: That's a broad question, you might as well start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable

Comment: check out this question regarding size estimation of BQ objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906717/is-there-a-way-to-estimate-table-or-field-size-in-bigquery

Comment: Thanks guys i got it... stackoverflow.com/questions/19906717/… –  user2881671